# Using Python script to get unread email

Tags: python, email

When I run the script below, it returns nothing, but i can't see any problem with the code.
Anyone know why?

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import imaplib
import email

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login('XXXXX@gmail.com','XXXXXX')
mail.list()
mail.select()
typ,data=mail.search(None,'UNSEEN')
print data
```

Usage:

```
$ python 1.py
['']
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your script and it returns empty list when no unread emails appear.
Then I sent myself an email, and the script returned ID of the new, unread email.

So your code **is** actually working.

Comment: Thx for testing, how come i always get empty value no matter whether i have unread mail or not...is there any other reason that could cause such problem